# Two different rewrite conditions in the same .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, rewrite, querystring

I need to create a rewrite condition for two specific files, according to the requested path in the URL. It's possible?

**Condition 1:** If the URL is `example.com/admin` go to `admin.php?uri=params`. That is:

- `example.com/admin/form` => `admin.php?uri=form`
- `example.com/admin/form/edit` => `admin.php?uri=form/edit`

etc...

**Condition 2:** If the URL takes *ANY OTHER* parameter (other than `/admin`), go to `index.php?uri=params`. Thus:

- `example.com/about` => `index.php?uri=about`
- `example.com/test` => `index.php?uri=test`
- `example.com/blau/bleu` => `index.php?uri=blau/bleu`

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin(?:$|/([^.]*))$ admin.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This does assume that none of your URLs (that need rewriting) contain dots (`.`). This avoids the need for a filesystem check to make sure the request does not map to a static resource, that would normally include a file extension (delimited by a dot).

`MultiViews` needs to be disabled (if not already) since you are requesting a URL `/admin` that is the basename of the file you are rewriting to. If MultiViews was enabled then `/admin.php` would be called without the URL parameter.

The `QSA` (Query String Append) flag is only required if you are expecting a query string on the original request, that would need to be appended to the rewritten URL.

A request for the document root (homepage) will call `index.php` *without* the `uri` parameter.

---

*Aside:* Just a note on terminology...

> If the URL takes ANY OTHER parameter (other than `/admin`)

What you are calling "parameter" here is really the URL-path (or path-segments). URL *Parameters* are the name=value pairs in the query string (what you are wanting to rewrite the request to).

In your example, you are rewriting the URL-path to a URL parameter value.